# In C++, how to ExtractFilePath of textfile

Tags: c++, find, filepath

I have made an application for a competition, which opens a text file and read all lines:

```
fstream infile("C:\Struct.in");
```

But the competition rules don't mention where the text file should be located in. Well, I guess it should be inside the folder, in which the program is located. So i could tell compiler to search in that folder:

```
fstream infile("C:\Users\User...Struct.in");
```

The problem in this case is that i don't know where exactly the examiner will put the folder, maybe he put it in the desktop, maybe he put it in his downloads... Which is a problem. Finally, i found that the best way to do this, is to order compiler find the location of the folder in runtime, then search the text file and do the rest, for example:

```
string ExePath = GetFilePath(Program's Exe);
string TextFilePath = ExePath + "Struct.in";
fstream infile(TextFilePath);
```

In pascal, the command is "ExtractFilePath", but i am new to C++, so is there any way to do this? So far, i have searched on the internet, but I couldn't find anything usefull.

I am using CodeBlocks 12.11 (Compiler: gnu gcc)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify a path, just the filename, it will be placed in the folder where the application is running.

```
fstream infile("Struct.in");
```

That's it.

Comment: Thanks, it is working and it's that simple, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

It should be `c:\\Struct` as `\` is the escape character. But the usual solution is just `"./Struct.in"`. Windows will understand the `/` character in this context, and `.` is the common name of the current directory.

Comment: So if i write  fstream infile("./Struct.in") it will get the location? Is it so simple?

Comment: It will get the "current" location, which is not magically what you need. But it is the default unless specifically specified otherwise. Judges will assume this, too.